# tnote in caption using threeparttable

Tags: tables, footnotes, threeparttable

I want to have a table with a caption and some footnotes. I decided to use threeparttable. When I use the code `\tnote{1}` in one of the table rows, it correctly displays a <sup>1</sup>. But when I use this code in the caption of the table, it doesn't display a thing. According to [this pdf](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttable/threeparttable.pdf),

> \tnote commands may be given in the caption too, and they will not
>   appear in the list of tables.

Is this simply an unsupported feature, or am I doing something wrong? This is (a slimmed down version of) my table:

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{List of bridges.\tnote{1}}
    \label{tb:listbridges}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Span (m)} & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Year} \\ \midrule
        Bridge 1 & 255 & Place 1 & 2010 \\
          \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
        \item[1] Adapted from data received from ...
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The caption must go *inside* the `threeparttable` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{threeparttable,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering % no center environment

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{List of bridges.\tnote{1}}
\label{tb:listbridges}

\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Span (m)} & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Year} \\
\midrule
Bridge 1 & 255 & Place 1 & 2010 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\item[1] Adapted from data received from ...
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\tnote` command simply gobbles its argument when outside a `threeparttable` environment.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point that, if you use `threeparttablex` and `longtable`, you can insert the table notes anywhere you please. The syntax is slightly different: table notes are declared in a `TableNotes` environment at the beginning of the `ThreePartTable` environment, and inserted with a `\insertTableNotes` command. Here is a demo:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttablex, longtable, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{List of bridges.\tnote{1}} \label{tb:listbridges}
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
      \toprule
      \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Span (m)} & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Year} \\ \midrule
      Bridge 1 & 255 & Place 1 & 2010 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
      \item[1] Adapted from data received from ...
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
%%
\begin{ThreePartTable}
  \setTableNoteFont{\footnotesize}
  \begin{TableNotes}\footnotesize
    \item[1] Adapted from data received from ...
  \end{TableNotes}
  \begin{longtable}{llll}
    \caption{List of bridges.\tnote{1}} \label{tb:listbridges}\\[-1ex]
    \insertTableNotes\\[0.5ex]
    \toprule
    \endfirsthead
    \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \insertTableNotes\\
    \endlastfoot
    \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Span (m)} & \textbf{Location} & \textbf{Year} \\ \midrule
    Bridge 1 & 255 & Place 1 & 2010 \\
  \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard, I don't think I need this right now, but I might in the future. So thank you for pointing it out.